# Filter array on multiple props, from one UI box

Tags: reactjs

I have built a filter that filters dog names based on UI in a search box. At the moment it searches name. But what if I want to be able to type in a breed, age, colour etc. how can I set it up to basically filter on all of the props of the dogs. So the user can type in a color or a breed and it will filter. Rather then only filtering on the one prop.

```
Const dogs = [

 {
  name:"rex",
  sex: "male",
  age: 6 
 }
]
```

Then my filter is as below:

```
Let filteredDogs= this.state.dogs.filter((dog) =>{
   return dog.name.toLowerCase().includes    
      (this.state.searchDog.toLowerCase())
   })
```

I’m assuming I just need to add another condition into the filteredDogs variable.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Are you sure your JSON architecture is correct ? Shouldn't your dog object be the following : `{ 
        name: "rex",
        sex: "male",
        age: 6
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coulp iterate over all values in your object using `Object.values` and then applying the function you gave to each of them.

Do not forget to convert them with `toString` otherwise the age property will not work :

```
let filteredDogs = this.state.dogs
    .filter(dog => Object.values(dog)
    .some(val => val.toString().toLowerCase()
    .includes(this.state.searchDog.toLowerCase())))
```

For this solution I considered your data to be the following :

```
const dogs = [
    { 
        name: "rex",
        sex: "male",
        age: 6
    },
    {
        name: "fred",
        sex: "female",
        age: 9
    },
]
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I stuffed that up I will correct it. So your answer should allow me to type anything in the search bar, and it filter against all of the props, eg name,sex,age? That’s what I’m aiming for. Rather than it only returning dogs that have a name which matches the search filter.

Comment: Yes it should, although I didn't test it and may have made a typo somewhere it should point you in the right direction

Comment: I’ll give it a go. I can’t find much information about it although I’m sure it is used very often. Thanks ..

Comment: That worked great @treycos. Nice and tidy too. Thank you very much